# Add line number when adding line to a file

Tags: python, io

From my main program I am calling in a loop a script which, as an output, adds a line of data to a txt file. What is the easiest way to include also the line number?

Here is the code I am  using:

```
if area > 1000: 
        f = open(output_file, "a")
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (a, b))
        f.close
```

Comment: You mean the line number based on the existing line count already in the file? You need to be clearer as to where the count would come from.

Comment: Yes I mean that. I want to add a `counter` so that when I add a line to the `output_file` this has value = number written lines + 1.

Comment: Do the other lines already have a counter each?

Comment: Yes: all the lines are written in the same way, and I want to include a counter for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to count the number of lines in the file already, before adding a new line with the counter incremented:

```
if area > 1000: 
    with open(output_file, "r+") as f:
        linecount = sum(1 for _ in output_file)
        f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (linecount + 1, a, b))
```

This is the simpler approach; it reads the whole file and counts the lines. For larger files, you'd have to read a chunk at the end to find the last line, then parse the last counter from that last line instead, to avoid reading through the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be opening the output file everytime. As for the counter, you can just maintain a counter yourself.

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as i, open(output_file, 'w') as o:
    count = 1
    for line in i:
        # do some computation
        if area > 1000:
            o.write('%d: %s %s\n' %(count, a, b))
            count += 1
```

Comment: I am forced to open the output file every time because I have a memory leak and that was the easiest way to avoid it.

Comment: Actually using `with` is far better because it closes the files on its own.